# Why the Color{} disturbs alignment inside Table?

Tags: tables

I am using Beamer to prepare my slides and found that the color{} disturbs the alignment (the colored word are not aligned with plain words in the same row). How to correct it?

```
 \begin{tabular}{ |p{0.5cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
    \hline
    Apple   & Boy &  {\color{red} Cat}     \\
    \hline
    Dog & Egg &  Fan     \\
    \hline 
    Gate        & Hat & {\color{red}Ink}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Use `\textcolor{red}{Cat} `, or `\leavevmode\color{red}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Can you write up an answer for this (so we can remove the current CW answer)?

Comment: @Werner I bet there is a duplicate somewhere,  I only hadn't the time to search.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by Ulrike in her comment, use \textcolor{red}{Cat}.